# Can't Play Online Videos on Firefox - openSUSE Leap 42.3

Tags: opensuse

I installed openSUSE Leap 42.3 and I can't play online videos using Firefox. Although YouTube videos work fine Twitch videos don't.

What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you will need to a install community-hosted codec repository.  A well-known repository is [opensuse-community.org](http://opensuse-community.org/), with one-click install.

You can view which codecs are available to your browser (on YouTube) at [youtube.com/html5](https://www.youtube.com/html5).  Twitch may use different codecs.  Check their troubleshooting page at [help.twitch.tv](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/en/portal/articles/2477288-html5-video-player-faq).